# FFmpeg combine mp3 files to one mp3 file with delays

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

How can I combine more files and add delay to all of them so the output will start silently?

I am trying to take a few `mp3` files and combine them all to 1 `mp3` file with delays using `ffmpeg`.

So far was only able to merge 2 `mp3` files and adding 10 second delay only to one of them.

I tried command this:

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mp3 -i aab.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000|10000[b];[0][b]amix" out.mp3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay):

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mp3 -i aab.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=10000|10000[a];[1]adelay=10000|10000[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2" out.mp3
```

Newer versions can use `10s` for a 10 second delay instead of declaring milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

From llogan answer, I am adding couple explanations.

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mp3 -i aab.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=10000|10000[a];[1]adelay=10000|10000[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2" out.mp3
```

aaa.mp3 is input 0

aab.mp3 is input 1

```
[0]adelay=10000|10000[a]
```

Means take input 0 and add a delay of 10000milliseconds on both channel and name the stream specifier 'a'

```
[1]adelay=10000|10000[b]
```

Take input 1 and add a delay of 10000milliseconds on both channel and the stream specifier 'b'

```
[a][b]amix=inputs=2
```

mix the stream specifier called 'a' and 'b'.

Here is a video that can help you to understand ffmpeg filter graph.
https://youtu.be/hElDsyuAQDA?t=341

Comment: nice explanation!